# Calculus : What's the largest interval of this function and is it a continuous one?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Say I have a piecewise-defined function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x+3 & \text{if}\; x \geq 1 \\ 2+3x & \text{if}\; x < 1 \end{cases}$$

What's the largest interval that this function can take to remain continuous? I am conflicted as to if its $(-\infty, 1)\cup[1,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$. And is the function continuous with no discontinuities? Because if it is, then the largest interval is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

Just check the continuity at $x=1$

So, $$f(1^-)=2+3*1=5$$
$$f(1)=2*1+3=5$$

So, $f$ is continuous everywhere i.e., $$x \in (-\infty,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you agree that the only point of $\mathbb R$ at which $f$ can be discontinuous is $1$. But$$\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=5=\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x).$$Therefore, it is continuous everywhere and the answer to your question is $\mathbb R$.